# Hits per day in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google Big Query to find hits per day. Here is my query,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Key, 
       DATE(EventDateUtc) AS Value 
FROM    [myDataSet.myTable] 
WHERE    ..... 
GROUP BY Value 
ORDER BY Value DESC 
LIMIT 1000;
```

This is working fine but it ignores the date with 0 hits. I wanna include this. I cannot create temp table in Google Big Query. How to fix this.

Tested getting error  `Field 'day' not found.`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Key, 
       DATE(t.day) AS Value  from (
       select date(date_add(day, i, "DAY")) day
from  (select '2015-05-01 00:00' day) a 
cross join
(select 
   position(
     split(
       rpad('', datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'2015-05-01 00:00')*2, 'a,'))) i 
 from (select NULL)) b

       ) d
left join [sample_data.requests] t on d.day = t.day
GROUP BY Value 
ORDER BY Value DESC 
LIMIT 1000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query data that exists in your tables, the query cannot guess which dates are missing from your table. This problem you need to handle either in your programming language, or you could [join with a numbers table and generates the dates on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966463/how-to-extract-unique-days-between-two-timestamps-in-bigquery).

If you know the date range you have in your query, you can generate the days:

```
select date(date_add(day, i, "DAY")) day
from  (select '2015-01-01' day) a 
cross join
(select 
   position(
     split(
       rpad('', datediff('2015-01-15','2015-01-01')*2, 'a,'))) i 
 from (select NULL)) b;
```

Then you can join this result with your query table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Key, 
       DATE(t.day) AS Value  from (...the.above.query.pasted.here...) d
left join [myDataSet.myTable] t on d.day = t.day
WHERE    ..... 
GROUP BY Value 
ORDER BY Value DESC 
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: I need only one query.

Comment: The second one is your query. The first one is just  to understand better the problem. You need to place the first query in the second, and it will work with one single query. Check it out.

Comment: @user960567 please take the time and read the query, and adapt to your table structure. You need to know where to place your own columns. Like you need to change t.day into your own structure to match it.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Now getting `Timestamp literal or explicit conversion to timestamp is required` But I got the idea

Comment: @user960567 you need to further convert the column into a date, you may need another level of subquery to do this conversion.

Comment: :) I think its better to use js or C#(means programming level) to emit date rather than complecate the query more