# How do I create a list of dates, before doing a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery SQL. I have the following tables:

```
Table "public.org" (records all organisations)
    Column    │          Type          │ Modifiers
──────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────
 code         │ character varying(6)   │ not null
 name         │ character varying(200) │ not null   
 setting      │ integer                │ not null    

 Table "public.spending" (records spending on chemical by org by month)
    Column         │          Type           │ Modifiers
───────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────────
 org_id            │ character varying(6)    │ not null
 month             │ date                    │ not null
 chemical_id       │ character varying(9)    │ not null
 actual_cost       │ double precision        │ not null
```

And I want to calculate the spending on a particular chemical by month, by organisation. The complication is if there was no spending by an organisation on that chemical in a month, there is simply no entry in the `spending` table, rather than a zero entry. However, I would like output (a null or zero result, I don't mind which).

Right now I have this, which gives me total spending for all organisations including those that had no entries, but does not separate spending out by month:

```
SELECT
  org.code AS code,
  org.name AS name,
  num.actual_cost as actual_cost
FROM (
  SELECT
    code,
    name
  FROM
    org
  WHERE
    setting=4) AS orgs
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (
  SELECT
    org_id,
    SUM(actual_cost) AS actual_cost
  FROM
    spending
  WHERE
    chemical_id='1202010U0AAAAAA'
  GROUP BY
    org_id) AS num
ON
  num.org_id = orgs.code
```

So now I need to extend it to do a LEFT JOIN by month *and* organisation. I know that I can get the unique months in the `spending` table by doing this:

```
SELECT month FROM spending GROUP BY month
```

(NB BigQuery doesn't support `UNIQUE`.)

But how do I get all the unique rows for month *and* organisation, and only *then* do a LEFT JOIN onto the spending?

Comment: BQ supports UNIQUE https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Comment: What's the purpose of selecting month when that is a limited list of 12 options which can be hardcoded in the query eg: (SELECT 1 as m, SELECt 2 as m...) it just slows down the query itself.

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanks! `month` is a slightly misleading column name, it's actually a whole bunch of dates across 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about calendar months there we have only 12 options (Jan => Dec).

Just compile a static table or in the query itself as 12 selects that form a table, and use that to join.

```
select * from 
(select 1 as m),
(select 2 as m),
....
(select 12 as m)
```

you might also be interested in the Technics mentioned in other posts :

- [How to extract unique days between two timestamps in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966463/how-to-extract-unique-days-between-two-timestamps-in-bigquery)
- [Hits per day in Google Big Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232685/hits-per-day-in-google-big-query/30232994#30232994)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in bigquery, but this is the structure of a query that does what you want:

```
select org.name, org.code, m.month, sum(s.actual_cost)
from org cross join
     (select month from public.spending group by month) m left join
     pubic.spending s
     on s.ord_ig = org.code and s.month = m.month
where prescribing_setting = 4
group by org.name, org.code, m.month;
```

Comment: Thanks - in BQ I see this error: `The JOIN operator's right-side table must be a small table. Switch the tables if the left-side table is smaller, or use JOIN EACH if both tables are larger than the maximum described at http://goo.gl/wXqgHs.`

Comment: I tried switching to `JOIN EACH` and I do get some results, but when I try to add in the filter expression (`WHERE setting=4 AND s.chemical_id='xxxxx'`) it does not return empty rows.

Comment: The condition on `s` needs to go in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggested following steps for you to get through:

**STEP 1** - identify months range (start and finish)
month is assumed to be presented in format YYYY-MM-01
if it is in different format - code should be slightly adjusted

```
SELECT 
  MIN(month) as start, 
  MAX(month) as finish
FROM public.spending
```

Assume **Result of Step 1** is 
'2014-10-01' as start, '2015-05-01' as finish

**Step 2** - produce all months in between Start and Finish

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01'), pos - 1, "MONTH")) AS month
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, * FROM (FLATTEN((
  SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1000, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
))) nums 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT '2014-10-01' AS start, '2015-05-01' AS finish // <<-- Replace with SELECT from Step 1
) range
WHERE pos BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
AND DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01'), pos - 1, "MONTH")) 
    BETWEEN start AND finish
```

So, now - **Result of Step 2** is

```
month    
2014-10-01   
2014-11-01   
2014-12-01   
2015-01-01   
2015-02-01   
2015-03-01   
2015-04-01   
2015-05-01
```

It has all months, even if some are missed in public.spending table in between start and finish

I think the rest is trivial and you have already main code for it.
Let me know if this is not accurate and you need help in completing above steps